# $\frac{dx}{dt} = |x|^{1/2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Im looking to find 4 solutions to the ODE :

$\frac{dx}{dt} = |x|^{1/2} , x(0)=0$.

Clearly, $x=0$ is one solution.
Using seperation of variables for $x>0$ yields $x= t^2/4$ as another solution, and if we consider $x<0$, I find that $x = -t^2/4$. Could someone give a hint as to where I am missing the last solution?

Thanks!

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions. Can you guess how to obtain them from what you have?

Comment: my text states there exist 4 different solutions through (0,0)..perhaps a linear combination of x>0 and x<0 is what you mean?

Comment: Does it explicitly say "exactly four"? I doubt it. Not "linear combination", but some form of combination.

Comment: ahhhhhhhh I finally understand what you mean. the piece-wise functions stay the same- we can just alter the intervals on which theyre defined!

Comment: Yes, you can glue solutions together, since $\lvert x\rvert^{1/2}$ isn't Lipschitz-continuous at $0$. All $$f_{a,b}(t) = \begin{cases} -\frac14(a-t)^2 &, t \leqslant a\\ \qquad 0 &, a \leqslant t \leqslant b\\ \hphantom{-}\frac14(t-b)^2 &, b \leqslant t \end{cases}$$ are solutions ($-\infty \leqslant a \leqslant 0 \leqslant b \leqslant \infty$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I claim that a solution (the 'basic' solution) is

$$
x = \begin{cases} t^2/4 &:  t>0 \\
0&:  t \leq 0
\end{cases}
$$

Verify that this not only satisfies the DE and IC, but it is continuous everywhere, *with a continuous derivative*. (you only have to check the continuity and differentiability at $x=0$ since it is obviously smooth everywhere else).

Now think about what happens if you translate this function to the right.

**EDIT** additional thoughts

Another way to go about this that avoids translation would be to show that you can take $x$ to be either $t^2/4$ or $0$ on $[0,\infty)$ and either $-t^2/4$ or $0$ on $(-\infty,0)$, and that no matter which of these four options you choose, the result satisfies the DE, IC, and is continuous w/ continuous derivative.

I.e. 
$$
x = \begin{cases} t^2/4 &:  t>0 \\
-t^2/4 &: t \leq 0
\end{cases}
$$

$$
x = \begin{cases} t^2/4 &:  t>0 \\
0 &: t \leq 0
\end{cases}
$$
etc. are all solutions.